# TransactionManager Websphere vs Weblogic

Tags: java, transactions, websphere, weblogic, transactionmanager

We have migrated an internal system from Weblogic to Websphere and it has been noticed that the weblogic implementation of the TransactionManager would flush the commands to the database immediately when commiting a nested transaction. In the other hand the implementation of websphere seems to wait the suspended transaction to finish to flush the nested ones.

Example:

```
Weblogic Implementation of TransactionManager
T1 begin
T1 suspended T1.1 begin
             T1.1 commit *T1.1 results visible in the DB
T1 resume
T1 commit *T1 results visible in the DB

Websphere Implementation of TransactionManager
T1 begin
T1 suspended T1.1 begin
             T1.1 commit 
T1 resume
T1 commit *T1.1 AND T1 results visible in the DB at this point.
```

Any thoughts are welcome.

PS: as far as our investigation has gone both are supposed to be working with transaction isolation level READ_COMMITED. 
The database is Oracle.

Comment: How are you suspending and resuming transactions?

Comment: I am not following your diagram. In simple term, Are you saying after migrated to Websphere your seeing different behaviour? What is the impact? I have worked with a J2EE application which supports WL, Websphere and JBoss and I didn't notice any issues.

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit more about the APIs you're using to suspend the tran, and work with the DB (JPA, JDBC, etc).

Comment: @Alasdair Using suspend and resume methods from TransactionManager

Comment: @MinhKieu The difference in the behaviour is when the changes done in a nested transaction are visible for other connections/transactions to read in the database, in weblogic when the nested transaction execute commit the changes are visible in the DB, in websphere just when the parent transaction commits.

Comment: @ScottKurz we use Apache OFBIZ, and it uses UserTransaction and TransactionManager to manage the transactions, weblogic and websphere delivers their own implementations of these interfaces.

Comment: @Roger, that sounds strange. I can understand that the dB may want to see the new records for checking constrains but other connections/transactions should not be able to see uncommitted data. Are you sure your nested transactions not starting a new transaction? And what about transaction boundary?

Comment: Hi @MinhKieu,The system uses suspend and resume from TransactionManager interface, it seems to me that the implementation of Weblogic flushes the nested transaction changes immediately, while the websphere do not, and flushes altogether with the parent transaction. 
I do not know how each TransactionManager treats it's suspended transaction... could not find documentation about it and at this particular moment I don't have the time to go through the decompiled code of each one =(

Comment: Further investigation has shown that the difference maybe in the implementation of UserTransaction or in a different behavior between the two servers. Looks like in some spots of the code where a transaction was not expected or at least not active, in websphere there is a transaction and it is active. I'll keep posting the updates... I have managed to mimic the old(weblogic) behavior now by suspending the current active transaction and beginning a new one.

Comment: WAS doesn't do nested transactions. Based on the behavior you describe it sounds like you were trying to suspend and then resume using an unsupported API which didn't actually suspend the transaction. That said you seem to have solved it which is good.